# How to get result like CakePHP, with INNER JOIN (PDO)? Is it possible using only PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp, pdo

From this query, I want to get data like this with INNER JOIN using PDO. How CakePHP can get data like?

`SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN group ON users.group_id = group.id`

CakePHP will show a array like this:

`Array
Users
|-- id
|-- name
|-- phone
|-- group_id
Group
|-- id
|-- name`

PDO:

`Array
|-- id
|-- name
|-- phone
|-- group_id`

How to split data like CakePHP? Is it possible with PDO/MYSQL/PHP?

Comment: If two tables have same fields eg id and name, you need an alias for that, eg select user.id as userID ... etc

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is to return an associative array keyed by the name (or alias) of the model.

If you wish to deal only with field names, you can use the `Hash` class.

For example, with the following code:

```
$results=$this->User->query("SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN group ON users.group_id = group.id");
$users=Hash::extract($results, '{n}.Users');
```

`$users` should look like:

```
Array
    |-- id
    |-- name
    |-- phone
    |-- group_id
```

Take a look at the Cookbook for more information: [Hash Class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html).